# upload array of items to json API ios

Tags: ios, json

I have an ios app where I can easily upload data such as a string to json and phpMyAdmin database.

```
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"uploadData", @"command", titleText.text, @"Title", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //completion

    NSLog(@"json: %@", json);

    if (![json objectForKey:@"error"]) {
        //success
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Your data has uploaded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

    } else {
        //error, check for expired session and if so - authorize the user
        NSString* errorMsg = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
        [UIAlertView error:errorMsg];
        if ([@"Authorization required" compare:errorMsg]==NSOrderedSame) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil];
        }
    }
}];
```

However, I would like to add an array of items from my tableView.

```
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"uploadGuests", @"command", self.tableData, @"Names", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //completion

    NSLog(@"json: %@", json);

    if (![json objectForKey:@"error"]) {
        //success
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Your table data has uploaded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

    } else {
        //error, check for expired session and if so - authorize the user
        NSString* errorMsg = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
        [UIAlertView error:errorMsg];
        if ([@"Authorization required" compare:errorMsg]==NSOrderedSame) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil];
        }
    }
}];
```

I use this API.php to to upload to database which works if the data is a string or int but not for an array.

```
$result = query("INSERT INTO NamesTable(Names) VALUES('%s')", $Names);
```

My question is what is the best way to upload my table data with json?

Comment: Using a dictionary I expect or an array of dictionaries if you want to upload multiple rows.

Comment: are you sure your DB query is working fine??

Comment: try INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4);